# How can a container/wrapper <div> be full screen in a complex page

Tags: html, fullscreen

This question arises when I tried the proper solution to a container  which had multiple internal divs.
This works fine with a simple div in body

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
}

    #wrapper {
        min-height: 100%; 
        height:100%; <!-- if IE -->
        width: 100%;
        min-width:100%;
        background-color:#990000;
    }
```

-- well ain't that typical of this week: 60 hours of work creating by the book html and 1/10th is billable because it does not work: instructions don't work though followed to the letter; and they say nothing about having to highlight the entry and then hit tab to make id show up in the draft window!--

Why doesn't this work in a more complex page wherein the #wrapper becomes #container_toolbox with several more divs within it. In both I.E. and Mozilla there is always a gap at the right. Why?

```
html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
   #container_toolbox   
    {
        min-height: 100%; 
        height:100%; <!-- if IE -->
        width: 100%;
        min-width:100%;
            background-color:#99000;
    }
```

Now, if I replace the first code with second in a test page, it works perfectly. Why, when there are nested divs within this #container_toolbox, does it not work.
I am using both Dreamweaver and Aptana'a download to create pages.

---

here are the two samples: the first is the one that works:

```
    <head>
        <title>ggggg</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
             html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }
           #container_toolbox   
            {
                min-height: 100%; 
                height:100%; <!-- if IE -->
                width: 100%;
                min-width:100%;
                background-color: #990000;
            }

        </style>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        <style type="text/css">
            #container {
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container_toolbox">
            <p> in mature regions, and changes of focus among a large 
                                pack of shops as various markets undergo change. How do you pick the right one to 
                                work with you at any point in time? -- Well, maybe you shouldn't pick one.</p> 


        </div>
    </body>


Here is the one that doesn't work I've had to eliminate html5 tags frequently:
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>

  <!-- Use the .htaccess and remove these lines to avoid edge case issues.
       More info: h5bp.com/b/378 -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Toolbox</title>

<link href="../styles/toolbox_stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="../styles/basic_style_2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" >
document.createElement("header");
document.createElement("hgroup");
document.createElement("section");
document.createElement("article");
document.createElement("footer");
document.createElement("nav");
</script>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
#container_toolbox  
{
            min-height: 100%; 
            height:100%; <!-- if IE -->
            width: 100%;
            min-width:100%;


}

</style>


</head>

<body>

<div id="container_toolbox">
<!--start container for page-->
<!--top section includes: header with logo; aside with contact info...
site navigation-->
    <div id="head">
            <div id="logoDiv"><img src="../images/headerLogo.jpg" alt="Fabshops.com"></div>
            <div class="aside" id="contactAside">
                <p>Phone: (973) 738 2599</p>
                <p>Email: <a href="mailto:info@fabshops.com">info@fabshops.com</a> </p>
      </div>
            <div class="nav f" id="mainNav">
                <ul class="navul" id="ulMainNav">
                    <li><a href="../welcome.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../ProductTypes/ProductTypes.html">Equipment Types</a></li>
                    <!--<li><a href="../About/about.html">About</a></li>-->
                    <li><a href="../contact/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../newsletter/newsletter.html">Newsletter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="toolbox.html">Toolbox</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div id="accentLine">   </div>

    <!--body section includes: inner navigation; articles; aside-->
    <!--*********************************************************************-->
    <!--*********************************************************************-->
    <article id="content_toolbox">
    <!--begin content section-->
    <!--*********************************************************************-->
        <!--begin sideNav-->
        <nav class="nav" id="sideNav">
            <div class="nav" id="sideHeader">
                <h2>Tool Box</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="lowerNav">
                <ul class="sidenavul" id="sideNavList">
                    <li><a href="../welcome.html">Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!--End sideNav-->
        <!--*********************************************************************-->
        <section class="sectionhd_toolbx" id="sectionhd_toolbx">
            <!--begin contents of section head-->
                    <h1>Select the converter appropriate for your purposes.</h1>
                    <h2>Make sure your browser permits Javascript</h2>
            <!--end contents of lead article-->
        </section>
        <!-- ******************************************************************** -->
        <!--<section id="section_toolbx">--><!--begin contents of second article--><!--end contents of second article-->
        <!--</section>--> 
    <!--end content section-->
    <section id="toolbox">
        <!-- Put the toolbox into a table as margin-left/rignt:auto is not working here -->
            <!-- Begin toolbox table -->
                <table class="tbtoolbx" id="tbtoolbox">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="tdleft">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td id="tdmiddle">

                <!--begin iframe section-->
                              <p><a href="../toolbox/Capacity_Volume.html" target="calcIframe">Volume & Capacity</a> | 
                                <a href="PressureConverter.html"                    target="calcIframe">Pressure
                                  Converter</a> | <a href="LengthConverter.html" target="calcIframe">Length
                                  Converter</a> | <a href="WeightConverter.html" target="calcIframe">Weight
                                  Converter</a> | <a href="CurrencyConverter.html" target="calcIframe">Currency
                                  Converter</a><br>
                                <a href="TemperatureConverter.html" target="calcIframe">Temperature Converter</a></p>
                              <iframe name="calcIframe" src="../toolbox/Capacity_Volume.html" scrolling="no">You
                              need a Frames Capable browser to view this content. </iframe>
                              <!--end iframe section-->                     </td>
                      <td id="tdright"></td>
                  </tr>
      </table> <!-- EndBegin toolbox table -->
    </section>
    </article>
    <!-- ************************************************************************* -->
    <!--***************************************************************************-->
<!--footer-->
<div class="footer" id="foot">
    <p><<a href="../welcome.html">Home</a> | <a href="../ProductTypes/ProductTypes.html">Equipment Types | <a href="../About/OurShops.html">Our Shops</a> | <a href="../contact/contact.html">Contact</a> | <a href="../newsletter/newsletter.html">Newsletter</a> | <a href="../toolbox/toolbox.html">Toolbox</a></p>
    <p>Fabshops.com is a subdivision of Ridgeback Company, Inc</p>
    <p>Headquarters: 61 Ormont Road, Chatham, NJ 07928</p>
    <p>Web site designed by <a>TutorWright</a></p>
</div>
<!--end container for page-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: css comments don't work like html comments. in css you have to use /* add comment her */

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your inner divs have margins that are overflowing the container div and, in effect, becoming margins on it. Try `{overflow: hidden;}` on the wrapper.

It's hard to say for sure without some HTML or a demo, however.

Comment: Thanks, but it solves lateral problem but prevents scrolling down page.

Comment: Or maybe try {overflow: auto;}.